# Rails: Custom nested controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-action, nested-routes, controller-action

I want to setup a custom nested controller actions but I can't figure out the routing.

I keep getting the following error

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets"
```

routes.rb

```
resources :companies do
  resources :requests do
    match :accept
  end
end
```

index.html.rb

```
<% @requests.each do |request| %>
  <ul class="users">
    <li>
    <%= full_name(request.profile) %> 
    <%= request.status %> 
    <%= link_to "Accept",
            :controller => "requests", :action => "accept",
            :id => request.id %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As you get closer to a working solution, please leave the original question intact to help other people who find this page in future. You've now edited the question so much that the answers look irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have rolled it back to the original question

Comment: No problem, it's just always worth thinking about two things on SO: Getting help with your immediate problem and helping people who find this question on Google later.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a couple of problems: routing to the `accept` action and building a URL to a nested resource.

#### Defining custom actions

You can add custom actions to your RESTful resources using this syntax:

```
resources :requests do
  get 'accept', :on => :member
end
```

This will give you a route that looks like this:

```
requests/:id/accept
```

And you can generate paths in your views using:

```
accept_request_path(a_request)
```

The `:on => :member` part indicates that you're routing to a new action on each individual request, rather than the collection of all requests. If you used `:on => :collection` the route would be `requests/accept`

#### Nesting resources

When you nest resources:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :requests do
    get 'accept', :on => :member
  end
end
```

You get routes that look like this, note that because the requests is nested inside companies the route includes both a `company_id` and an `id`:

```
companies/:company_id/requests/:id/accept
```

And helpers like this:

```
accept_company_request_path(a_company, a_request)
```

You could do this long-hand, as you're currently trying to do, with something like:

```
<%= link_to "Accept",
        :controller => "requests", :action => "accept",
        :id => request.id, :company_id => request.company.id %>
```

But it's easier to use the helpers:

```
<%= link_to "Accept", accept_company_request_path(request.company, request) %>
```

#### Appropriate verbs

Accept sounds a lot like something that updates your database in some way, and if that's the case you should consider using a `PUT` request rather than a `GET` request.

The HTTP/1.1 spec says that *the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval* ([RFC2616, section 9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)) which has the real-world implication that non-human web clients — search engine indexers, browser extensions, etc. — are allowed to follow links (which make `GET` requests) but not allowed to submit forms that make other types of requests.

If you do switch to using a `PUT` request then the [`button_to` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) will come in handy. As with `link_to` you can pass the controller, action, method, and all the parameters required by the route to `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to 'Accept',
      {:controller => :requests, :action => :accept,
       :company_id => request.company, :id => request},
      :method => :put %>
```

Or you can use the helpers to generate the path which is much easier:

```
<%= button_to 'Accept',
      accept_company_request_path(request.company, request),
      :method => :put %>
```

#### More documentation

- [Adding more RESTful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)
- [Nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: Thanks, That is one of the most detailed and clear answer I have come across to date

Comment: Will using PUT just require changing the code for route from GET to PUT?

Comment: You'll need to change the route, and also change the view to use a `<form>` instead of a link (`<a>`). The `button_to` helper I linked to in the answer will help generate the form (and a [bit of CSS](http://natbat.net/2009/Jun/10/styling-buttons-as-links/) can make it look like a link, if that's what you want)

Comment: I have made the changes that you have suggested, but am still encountering a similar issue. what does the :member symbol represent.

Comment: I've further clarified the question and updated it with new error and code

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify what `:on => :member` means, you should also follow the links in the answer for a more complete explanation in the routing docs.

Comment: More updates: This time about using `button_to`.  I think you would benefit from reading the whole of the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html); it explains many of the things that have come up in this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13265/discussion-between-georgebrock-and-aaron-dufall)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, good advice I'm on to it right now

Comment: @georgebrock thank you for your answer: what if you wanted to do all that you've suggested above AND customise the route helper method's name: i tried using the "as:" keyword, but it doesn't relinquish full control. any advice?

Answer (score 2):

in your route file:

```
match 'request/accept/:id' => 'requests#accept', :as => :accept
```

and in view

```
link_to "Accept", accept_path(request)
```