# How to add a nested route resource to all existing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, paper-trail-gem

I am using a great gem called paper_trail.  I have created a page called 'history' that will list the versions for any resource.  My routes file has a nested resource for EVERY route...which is not DRY at all.

```
resources :users do 
  get "/history" => "pages#history", as: "history"
end
```

this route gives me users/1/history

```
resources :companies do 
  get "/history" => "pages#history", as: "history"
end
```

now I have companies/1/history

How can I make the /history work as a nested route for ALL routes without filling my routes file with a nested history path for every resource?

Comment: Did you get this answered? Could you post your controller as well?

Comment: I haven't found the"rails way" I was looking for.  My controller isn't important in this questions...and this affects every controller.  The way I have adapted @jkeuhlen block suggestion is to create an array of all models then iterating over that array and converting the string value in the array to a symbol and build a dynamic history route resource for each model in the array.  Hope that makes sense.  Its a bit cleaner...but, not the "rails way" I hoped to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do these types of actions in a block to avoid repeating yourself over and over.

```
resources :users, :companies do 
  get "history" => "pages#history", :on => :member
end
```

Some additional helpful information is available on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273069/rails-custom-nested-controller-actions).

Comment: This is a bit cleaner than nesting the history resource inside a block for each route.  I haven't been able to find anything cleaner...sure seems like rails would have a cleaner way to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the only 'rails way' to do this. It's messy when you have 10+ resources but its better than having each block separately.