# Nested resource from own controllers method - or create completely new controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue**: When a user (when signed in) creates an order, they are sent to the OrderControllers show page which can only be accessed if signed in by both the buyer and seller.  From here they can edit/update their order, etc.

We also have `guest_user`, someone who isn't signed in, and for them I need a order confirmation in the browser (I'm using Devise gem)

**I have created a method:**

```
def order_confirmation
```

In the OrdersController.

Although, how can I nest this within orders so the page knows which order to show.

Is this possible to nest methods under its' own controllers, or should i just create a small controller only for order confirmations?

**For example**: example.com/orders/1/order-confirmation

Maybe there are better ways to go about this other than just nesting and creating a controller?

**I Tried**:

```
  resources :orders do
    collection do
      get 'order_confirmation'
    end
  end
```

**With**:

```
  def order_confirmation
    @order = Order.all.find(params[:id])
  end
```

But it won't work how i want i t seems.

**The rake routes gives me**:

```
order_confirmation_orders GET    /orders/order_confirmation(.:format)
```

**How can i get?**:

```
order_order_confirmation_orders GET    /orders/id/order_confirmation(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out from the help of this SO post:

[Rails: Custom nested controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273069/rails-custom-nested-controller-actions)

**By using:**

```
resources :orders do
  get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
end
```

**This creates:**

```
 order_confirmation_order GET    /orders/:id/order_confirmation(.:format)                                                 orders#order_confirmation
```